# After logged in with Facebook, ParserUser.currentUser() returns null

Tags: android, parse-platform

I've just started to work on Parse API and I've found out that on my test device and emulator, the facebook integration doesn't work as expected.

In a onClickListener, I have this to log in with Facebook account:

```
    ...SignInActivity.onCreate()....
    List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "user_about_me",
        "user_relationships", "user_birthday", "user_location");
    ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(permissions, SignInActivity.this, new LogInCallback() {
      @Override
      public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        if (user == null) {
          Log.d("Parse",
              "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
        } else if (user.isNew() && err == null) {
          Log.d("Parse",
              "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
          startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        } else if (err == null) {
          Log.d("Parse",
              "User logged in through Facebook!");
          startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        } else {
          Log.d("Parse", "Login err: "+err.getMessage());
        }
      }
    });
```

I do check that err is null as well and this step logs users in correctly.

Then it sends me to MainActivity but when I exit the app and open it again,

```
....at the end of SignInActivity.onCreate()...

ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
if ((currentUser != null) && ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(currentUser)) {
  startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
} else {
  Log.d("Logging in with Facebook", "User not logged in. (currentUser != null) = " + (currentUser != null));
}
```

Tells me getCurrentUser() returned null.

In Application.onCreate(), I've the following code to set up Parse and ParseFacebookUtils.

```
Parse.initialize(this, "xxxx",
    "xxxxx");
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(getString(R.string.app_id));

super.onCreate();
```

I'm using facebook sdk v3.15.0 and Parse 1.5.1

Is this a known issue or am I missing something?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known Parse 1.5.1 bug, as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/229876443869758/

There is a workaround, for now: try to disable the local datastore.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the clarification! I'm working on migrating my current app (which stores data locally) to Parse backend. Since I don't have previous experience with Parse, do you know how much change it would need to enable local datastore?